# Python 3.7.2 Turtle source folder-specific error message

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-3.7

I have installed Python 3.7.2 in Windows 7. When I write turtle code and save it in the Python folder, it runs without errors. If I save it in another folder, it returns this error:

> NameError: name dot is not defined.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

from turtle import *

def triangle():

    fd(200);left(135);fd(150);goto(0,0)

def rectangle():

    lt(180);fd(250);lt(90);fd(125);lt(90);fd(250);lt(90);fd(125)

def square():

    fd(250);rt(90);fd(250);rt(90);fd(250);rt(90);fd(250)

def grdk():

    circle(75)

window=Tk()

window.title('GeoFigs')

window.geometry('250x200')

label=Label(window,text='Choose one figure',font='Aharoni -22 bold')

label.pack()

sekunga=ttk.Button(window,text='TRIANGLE',command=triangle)

sekunga.pack()

chor=ttk.Button(window,text='RECTANGLE',command=rectangle)

chor.pack()

kv=ttk.Button(window,text='SQUARE',command=square)

kv.pack()

grd=ttk.Button(window,text='CIRCLE',command=grdk)

grd.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full traceback of the exception you're getting? Because the error message mentions `dot` which doesn't appear anywhere in your code. It would help us a lot to know where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with your "NameError: name dot is not defined" issue but I wouldn't begin to debug a turtle program set up like this one.  Turtle is designed to work in either *standalone* (turtle alone) or *embedded* (turtle and tkinter) mode but you have it embedded in standalone mode which risks creating two Tk roots and other issues.  Below is a rework of your turtle code in *embedded* mode:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import ScrolledCanvas, TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

def triangle():

    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.home()

def rectangle():

    turtle.left(90)

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(250)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(125)

def square():

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.right(90)

def circle():

    turtle.circle(75)

window = Tk()
window.title('Graphics')
window.geometry('640x480+300+0')

figures = Toplevel(window)
figures.title('Figures')
figures.geometry('250x150')

Label(figures, text='Choose one figure').pack()

Button(figures, text='TRIANGLE', command=triangle).pack()
Button(figures, text='RECTANGLE', command=rectangle).pack()
Button(figures, text='SQUARE', command=square).pack()
Button(figures, text='CIRCLE', command=circle).pack()

canvas = ScrolledCanvas(window)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.screensize(640, 480)

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)

screen.mainloop()
```

Try this out and if the "NameError: name dot is not defined" persists, provide us a full error backtrace as an edit to your original question.